# get current variable Rails, in before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Is there a way to get the current variable?
lets say that i have a "title" attribute in a method and i want to check in with the old value of the variable ?

how could i accomplish this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ActiveRecord provides a whole set of methods which work on "[Dirty](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty)" attributes.

In your case, you can call `title_was` to get the most recently saved version of that variable

Comment: Thanxs! i wasn't able to find it in the api. But i didn't know what i was searching for :P..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know all the changed attribute and their old values you can use **changed_attributes** method which will return hash that contains all the changed attribute with their previous values (note that the hash content can be retrieve before saving the new object).

Let assume that you have an object with old_name title:

```
a = YourModel.where(:title => "old_name")
a.title = "new_title"
a.changed_attributes
```

Results will be":
{"title"=>"old_name"}

But after saving your changes:

```
a.save
a.changed_attributes
```

The results will be empty hash:
{}